# Android- bottom bar tab

Tags: android, android-layout

Need to create an application in a below mentioned link format targeting all the android platform i.e. from 1.5 to 4.1

http://natieklopper.blogspot.in/2011/08/iphone-styled-bottom-aligned-tab-bar.html

Can I use tab activity class for the same? Know it is deprecated but still need to confirm if we use then will my application work on all android devices.
Not getting appropriate demo or example to start my application with fragments,action bar sherlock's tab.

Please suggest me a simple way to initiate my application. Really appreciate if some examples are available.

Comment: your code is working find in every device. if you want to modify your code with actionbar sharelock's tab then check this links: http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-adding-actionbar-navigation-tabs.html and http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-adding-actionbar-navigation.html

Comment: Don't use bottom tab bars: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Your application will work in all android devices if they have a newer version than 1.5

Deprecated means obsolete, but you can continue using  ;)